# Extra space on right of html?

Tags: html, css, space

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Risebush|home</title>
</head>

<body bgcolor=linear-gradient(#82FA58, #21610B), >
<div style="color:#61B329">
<div id="header">
<div id="navbar">
<ul>
<li>Home</li>
<li>About Us</li>
<li>Become a Member</li>
<li>Contact Us</li>
<li>Games</li>
<li>Movies</li>
</ul>
</div>
  <h1 align="center", style="font-family:cursive"><font size="7">Risebush Website</font></h1>
</div>
</div>
  <p style="font-family:cursive">Risebush is awesome! We do things and stuff. We have lots of employees working for us and are rolling in the cash as you read this!</p>
<p style="font-family:cursive">$$$$$ = life</p>
<img src="http://previews.123rf.com/images/pamparam/pamparam0705/pamparam070500006/908484-Rainbow-over-the-green-meadow-and-multicolored-bush-in-bloom-Stock-Photo.jpg" alt="Rainbow over a bush" style="width:304px;height:228px">
<div style="color:#21610B" >
<p></p>
<a href='#' class='button'>Become a member!</a>
</div>
<div style="color:#21610B">
<h1 align="center", style="font-family:cursive"><font size="5">Games</font></h1>
</div>
<p></p>
<div align="center"><embed src="http://www.classicgamesarcade.com/games/flappybirdflash.swf" width="475px" height="665px" autostart="true" loop="false" controller="true"></embed><br /><a href="http://www.classicgamesarcade.com/game/21741/flappy-bird-game.html">Play Flappy Bird</a></div>
<div id="footer">
<p>&copy2011 Risebush, Azhi Guore</p>
<p>All rights reserved. You may not claim to own Risebush, in any way, shape, or form, or claim that you created this website in any way possible, all rights go to the Risebush Company, owned by Azhi Guore.</p>
</body>

<style media="screen" type="text/css">

.button {
   border: 1px solid #0a3c59;
   background: #3e779d;
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#65a9d7), to(#3e779d));
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #65a9d7, #3e779d);
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #65a9d7, #3e779d);
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #65a9d7, #3e779d);
   background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #65a9d7, #3e779d);
   background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #65a9d7 0%, #3e779d 100%);
   padding: 14.5px 29px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 22px;
   -moz-border-radius: 22px;
   border-radius: 22px;
   -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 1px 0, inset rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 1px 0;
   -moz-box-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 1px 0, inset rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 1px 0;
   box-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 1px 0, inset rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 1px 0;
   text-shadow: #7ea4bd 0 1px 0;
   color: #06426c;
   font-size: 21px;
   font-family: helvetica, serif;
   text-decoration: none;
   vertical-align: middle;
   }
.button:hover {
   border: 1px solid #0a3c59;
   text-shadow: #1e4158 0 1px 0;
   background: #3e779d;
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#65a9d7), to(#3e779d));
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #65a9d7, #3e779d);
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #65a9d7, #3e779d);
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #65a9d7, #3e779d);
   background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #65a9d7, #3e779d);
   background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #65a9d7 0%, #3e779d 100%);
   color: #fff;
   }
.button:active {
   text-shadow: #1e4158 0 1px 0;
   border: 1px solid #0a3c59;
   background: #65a9d7;
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#3e779d), to(#3e779d));
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3e779d, #65a9d7);
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3e779d, #65a9d7);
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3e779d, #65a9d7);
   background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3e779d, #65a9d7);
   background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3e779d 0%, #65a9d7 100%);
   color: #fff;
   }
#footer{
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    bottom: -20px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
    height: 95px;
    background-color: #3c4543;
}

#navbar {
        position:relative;
    margin-left:-350px;
    top:144px;
    left:50%;
}

#header {
    position:relative;
    top: -50px;
    background-color: #3c4543;
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;
}
ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    margin: 50px;
}

li {
    display: inline;
    border: 2px solid #000000;
    font-family: Futura, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px;
    background-color: #cc0323
}
</style>

</html>
```

The website looks fine as is, but there is a gigantic space on the right side of the page. However, I don't have any width parameters in my coding, so I don't know what could have possibly caused that gigantic space. Is there a way that I can remove it without ruining the website layout? Do you know what may have cause it? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @ASGM be careful there: jsfiddle is not a substitute for a question which contains code. It is a very helpful addition.

Comment: The CSS should be in the `<head>`.  @ASGM Separate CSS file is bad advice.  Putting it in a separate file will delay Start Render until the CSS file is retrieved.  The HTTP Request-Response is typically 200-500ms.  Whereas the transmission time for this 2.8KB CSS is less than 1ms.

Answer (score 0):

The only space that I see when checking your code out in the wild is from the default margin of the HTML body element. Try adding `body { margin: 0; }` to your stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `relative position` of `#navbar`. Just remove the `position:relative` and it will remove the gigantic space from right side. And then you need to adjust the position of your #navbar by adjusting margin-left which is -350px and all other necessary properties.